# Reading a fortran binary file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fortran

I have a binary file with the following instructions on how to read it in fortran:

```
OPEN (UNIT=UNIT_FILE_TXT, FILE="output/file.txt",
     &      FORM='UNFORMATTED',
     &      ACCESS='DIRECT',RECL=400,ERR=100,STATUS='UNKNOWN')
READ (UNIT=UNIT_FILE_TXT, REC= X) 

! loop for measurements in file.txt (binary file)
  DO I=RECENT, RECEXIT
     READ(FILEUNITTXT, REC=I) c1, c2, c3, c4, 
 &                    c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9
         ENDDO
```

I need to read the file using Python instead but I don't know if it is at all possible given that no dtype information is provided for the specific columns (or more specifically, I know from a related text file that e.g. c1 is I7, c2 is I2 but I have this information only for some of the columns).

My question is: is the information provided in the fortran guidelines above sufficient to read the file without having to spend time on trying to guess the column types?

I've tried, e.g.

```
arr = np.fromfile(inFile,
                  np.dtype([('c1','int32'),
                           ('c2','int32'),
                           ...
                           ('cn','float32')]))
```

But evidently my guesses as for the types are not correct as the values are definitely rubish.

Any help/hint would be much appreciated!

Comment: You mist show the declaration of the datatypes in Fortran, we have no idea what type are those `c1` and others. Look for similar question asked before, there are quite a few here. Because your file is direct access, there should be no record markers there.

Comment: @VladimirF Thank you for the comment. All I've got is the above info, as for the types I have partial information from a related file: 

Variable Format
C1  I7
C2 I2
C3 A9
…
(but not even for all the variables as the two files are not a one-to-one match)

From your answer I gather that indeed the info I have at hand is not sufficient to read the file?

Comment: No, it is not sufficient Fortran. You have to try to guess the types. We can't do that without the file. They could be 64 bit and they could also e big-endian, depending on the origin of the file.

Comment: Guessing is not optimal, but: The default implicit type for variables beginning with C is "REAL", i.e., float32, so if you have to guess, guess that. (And then you still have to guess endianess -- but a good start would be to guess that it's the same as the machine that generated the file.)